# IIS rewrite rules in a separate file to web.config needs to restart IIS itself to pick up changes

Tags: iis, iis-10, url-rewrite-module

I have an ASP.NET WebForms website which has a few Web.Config files for dev/UAT/production (the appropriate web.config is deployed to the relevant environment) - all of which reference a shared rewrite rule file - so that the rewrite rules themselves don't have to get duplicated into each web.config. This works great

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules configSource="WebConfigRewrites.Config" />
    </rewrite>
```

However, if I add a new rewrite rule to this file, then the rule doesn't take effect until I restart IIS. If I recycle the application pool, or restart the website in IIS the new rule doesn't work (e.g. a rewrite URL will throw a 404 until I restart IIS)

Is there any way around this? If I bring in the rules into the web.config then recycling the apppool, or even updating the web.config will cause these new rules to work - but at the cost of having to duplicate all the rules across several files.

Having to restart IIS itself is really rubbish, as it causes the site to instantly respond with a "service unavailable" 503 error.

Is there any other way around this?

Server is Windows Server 2016, IIS 10.0.14393

Comment: You probably need to add extra spaces to all the `web.config` files that link to this shared config file so that IIS configuration system can trigger an update to pick up your changes. Since IIS is not open sourced and nothing is out there documenting the actual file monitoring mechanism, it is difficult to find other solutions.

Comment: Hmm, testing this locally and it does seem to work. I'll have to give it a shot in production, thank you.

Comment: Note that then you can just "touch" the files, https://superuser.com/a/764727

Comment: Good idea, thank you. Next time I'm updating my site with a new rewrite rule then I will give this a try

Comment: Strangely though, I thought editing the web.config file triggers a recycle of the app pool - in this case the new rules are picked up, but if I manually recycle the app pool from the IIS interface then it's not picking up the change. Pretty weird behaviour here.

Comment: Changes to `web.config` are monitored by both IIS and ASP.NET runtime, but the behaviors differ and no application pool occurs. On IIS side, a sequence of internal changes happen if your modification in certain sections needs to take effect immediately. On ASP.NET side, usually an AppDomain reload is triggered due to your modification in `<system.web>`. That's why your manual recycle has no effect. The issue you identified is that the file set as `configSource` is not being monitored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the discussion under comments is lengthy, post a summary here to avoid confusion.

Usually your edits in URL rewrite rule section in `web.config` takes effect immediately, as IIS monitors `<system.webServer>` actively in `web.config` files.

But, when you moved the rules to an external file via `configSource`, you observed that changes to those rules are no longer picked up by IIS immediately. That seems to indicate IIS does not monitor such external files actively. If you want to confirm that's by design or not, the only way is to contact Microsoft support via https://support.microsoft.com.

The workaround is also easy that you ["touch" the monitored files](https://superuser.com/a/764727) like `web.config`, so that manually trigger configuration refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we do not need to restart IIS after changing web.config.

Changes web.config will trigger the app to be reloaded by IIS as soon as there are 0 connections left to the app. You can stop and restart the app pool. Recycling app pool is not recommended and you should stop/start the respective app pool where you update.

Have you tried stopping the site first and then restarting it? 404 error means that IIS has detected that web.config has been updated. You can also generate logs to view details.

Comment: The mechanism of config file monitoring behind the scene is much more complex than you might imagine, so better make no assumption here. I believe someone with more than 4000 points here at Stack Overflow do have the knowledge on how to investigate.

Comment: Yes, the 404 error is in relation to IIS not "seeing" the new rewrite rule, not because of IIS detecting a web.config change. I don't want to downvote but this answer isn't very relevant.